# What is the name of this theorem and how do I prove it?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

A triangle is intersected by two transversals, both parallel to the base of the triangle. Two more triangles appear and all three are similar. Also the area of $cde=fdeg=fgab$.

Find the exact value of the quotient $$\frac{cd}{fa}$$
[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using the properties of similar triangles but it has lead nowhere, also the fact that the areas are equal but that has also not helped.

Comment: If two triangles are similar the bases and the height are proportional to a constant ratio $r$.  So the areas of the triangle being half the base times height will be proportional to $r^2$.

Comment: Or in other words..... the areas of two similar triangles are proporional to the square of the proportions of the sides.  So you know the proportions of the areas.  SO take the square root to get the proportions of the sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three triangles are similar.  So there are constants $r_1$ and $r_2$ so that $CF= r_1 CD$ and $CA = r_2 CD$ and $\frac {CD}{FA} = \frac {CD}{CA - CF} =\frac {C}{r_2 CD - r_1 CF} = \frac 1{r_2 - r_1}$.

The area of $\triangle CFG = A \triangle CDE + A( FDEG) = 2\times A \triangle CDE$ and the area of $\triangle CAB =A \triangle CDE + A(FGAB) = 3\times A \triangle CDE$

But if the base and height of $\triangle CDE$ are $b,h$ then the base and height of $\triangle CFG$ and $\triangle CAB$ are $r_1b,r_1h$ and $r_2b, r_2h$ and the area of the triangles are $A\triangle CFG = \frac 12r_1br_1h = (\frac 12bh)r_1^2 = r_1^2 A \triangle CDE=2A\triangle CDE$ and $A\triangle CAB = \frac 12r_2br_2h = (\frac 12bh)r_2^2 = r_2^2 A \triangle CDE=3A\triangle CDE$

So $r_1 = \sqrt 2$ and $r_2 = \sqrt 3$

So $\frac {CD}{FA} = \frac 1{r_2 - r_1} = \frac 1{\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2}$

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Since the smallest triangle and the two trapezoids have equal area, you know that

- the medium triangle has twice the area of the smallest triangle
- the largest triangle has three times the area of the smallest triangle.

Since the triangles are similar, this means the corresponding sides of the triangle are in a ratio that is the square root of the area ratio. For example, comparing the middle triangle with the smallest triangle, we have $\frac{\overline{CD}}{\overline{CF}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$. This is how you relate the information about area ratios to reason about side lengths.